Realtime Database y RecyclerView
Estoy desarrollando un aplicación que guarda productos en una base de datos en tiempo real permitiendo también su borrado. El problema es que cuando elimino un producto, me muestra una vista "sucia" del RecyclerView ya que aparece el listado antiguo de productos seguido del listado nuevo. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Incluyo, a continuación, captura de la aplicación así como el código de la activity.
¡Gracias!

class VerProductosActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //ViewBinding
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityVerProductosBinding

    //Lista de productos
    private lateinit var productosList: ArrayList<Producto>

    //RecyclerView
    private lateinit var productosRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    //Firebase
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

    //Adapter
    private lateinit var adapterProducto: AdapterProducto

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityVerProductosBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        productosRecyclerView = binding.rvProductos
        productosRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        productosRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        productosList = arrayListOf<Producto>()

        getProductos()
        binding.btnVolver.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }

    }

    private fun getProductos() {
        //Ruta de productos
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Productos")

        database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    productosList.clear()
                    for (productosSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val producto = productosSnapshot.getValue(Producto::class.java)
                        productosList.add(producto!!)
                    }
                   adapterProducto = AdapterProducto(productosList)
                    productosRecyclerView.adapter = adapterProducto
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }


Bienvenida. Por favor pon el código como texto por más que ya te haya respondido.

Muchísimas gracias. Solucionado. No me permitía incluir tanto código. He dejado el código de la activity que es donde se encontraba el fallo.

En base al código y lo que se puede ver en las capturas, la explicación que encuentro al problema es que cada vez que recuperas la información de la base de datos la agregas a una lista pero nunca le quitas elementos.
Prueba agregando productosList.clear() antes del for en tu función getProductos.

Por cierto, no tienes que crear un adapter cada vez que actualizas los datos. Lo puedes crear una sola vez en el método onCreate.
Y después del for donde estabas creando el Adapter debes agregar la siguiente línea:
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() 

Para reflejar los cambios en la interfaz tienes que usar la familia de métodos notify... del Adapter, puedes verlas todas en la documentación. La más simple es notifyDataSetChanged aunque es la que más abarca. Si te preocupa el rendimiento, es mejor utilizar las demás funciones en lo posible.
